# Adding two atomics in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

can I do something like (meaning no undefined behaviour), I don't care about the order :) :

```
typedef std::atomic<double> a_t;

static a_t a1(1);
static a_t a2(2);
static a_t a3(3);

void f1()
{
    a1.fetch_add(a2.load(std::memory_order::relaxed), std::memory_order::relaxed);        
};

void f2()
{
    a1.fetch_add(a3.load(std::memory_order::relaxed), std::memory_order::relaxed);        
};

th1 = std::thread(f1);
th2 = std::thread(f2);

th1.join();
th2.join();
```

Thank you!

Ps: This example is just for the sake of the question!

After this comment "I have a feeling that your example..." I added the below
Ps: Suppose many threads write and read from all these atomics on top on the one in the example above.

Comment: If you are asking if this is thread safe, then yes.

Comment: thank you, that's all I want. I can think of many scenarios, but yeah, only thread safety that I care about :) Thanks again!

Comment: Of course you can. It won't be an atomic operation though.

Comment: Good heavens. If you care about so little the Care Bears will come for you!

Comment: thanks! Just to confirm a1 will have 6 at the end of the joins?

Comment: of course of course, sorry stupid question!

Comment: I have a feeling that your example doesn't demonstrate what you really want to ask about. Particularly the code doesn't compile. There is no `start` member of `std::thread`. Also, in the shown code it doesn't even matter that `a2` and `a3` are atomics. Their values are unchanged throughout. You could have written `2` and `3` directly instead of the loads as well.

Comment: sorry sorry, no start (I didn't run this). It will start on construction. I agree about a2 and a3, but in my head there many threads reading and writing to these atomics :) I hope the answer does not change??!

Comment: This example code may not answer what you intend to be asking.  Both `a2` and `a3` never change and are never accessed by more than one thread.  It seems arbitrary that they are `std::atomic` to begin with.

Comment: I changed the question :)

Comment: Hard to tell without concrete example and explanation what you consider "unexpected behaviour" or not.

Comment: *"Suppose many threads write and read"* Don't try to describe your code. Show a [mcve] that we can compile and run.

Comment: @user17732522 same definition as the standard. I am pretty sure it's thread safe now. The order will be crazy but it's fine.

Comment: @Maths4Us Did you intend to ask about _undefined_ behavior?

Comment: Yes yes, so sorry, I made a mess of this question!! undefined behavior. Will change now or delete this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing to atomic variables never causes data races and so doesn't cause undefined behavior if done unsynchronized in multiple threads for reason of a data race, as would be the case for normal variables.

However, this doesn't prevent race conditions, which can have unexpected results, although no undefined behavior. For example here a load of `a2` may read one value which will be added to `a1` but before it is added to `a1` the value of `a2` may be changed by another thread. `load` and `fetch_add` are individually atomic, but the whole expression is not.

With relaxed operations threads also don't have to agree with the order in which multiple atomic variables are modified. Only the modification order of any given individual atomic is consistent.